# Using Spring Cloud Contract Stub Runner with manually created stubs

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I'm not sure whether using [spring-cloud-contract](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract) for the purpose which I mentioned in the title is right or not but I want to understand the use case of it in such scenario.

We are updating our integration tests to use Spring Cloud Contract. For the new features, we are following the documentation for creating stubs from YAML/Groovy and then using them in consumer side with spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner.

My concern is the stubs which were already written and being used. We don't want to spend time on re-writing them in Groovy/YAML to make Spring Cloud Contract to generate stubs as we already have the stubs.
Existing test configuration is as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = Application.class
)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8989, stubs = "classpath*:**/stubs/mappings/**/*.json", files = "classpath*:**/stubs")
class MyClientIT { ... }
```

When it comes to changing this test to use [spring-cloud-contract](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract), I'm stuck with how to configure stub-runner:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = Application.class
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(???)
public class MyNewClientIT {...}
```

Is it possible and advised to use Spring Cloud Contract for such a case? And if so, how can we make stub-runner to see locally stored (not stored as an artefact locally or remotely) stubs?

Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way will be to take the stubs and re-package them to follow the `META-INF/group.id/artifactid/mappings/...` folder structure. Then you can use the Stub Runner classpath mode to pick those stubs via ids.

Comment: Thank you, what should I define for `group.id` and `artifactid`? The ones from the project itself?

Comment: Yes. E.g. com.example/artifact-id. Btw everything is described in the documentation

Comment: Thank you Marcin, to be honest the documentation is more focused on the full adoption. It'd have been quite helpful to have a section for a mixed approach.

Comment: We will be working on that for the next release. One of our top priorities is to improve the documentation